# permutation with restriction - no two zeroes can be together from an set consisting of 3 zeroes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have this as data set - `0 1 0 1 0`
now how to find out the number of permutations with restriction that **no two zeroes can be together**.
i.e. 00110, 00011, 11000 etc. -> all these are false cases
I was trying with `5!/2!.3! - (cases where two zeroes are always together)`.

But I am able to find out how to do this? Any help ?

Comment: I would have tried the *Inclusion–exclusion principle*, I think it'll work the best.

Comment: @Georgey How to do that using that principle.. m not getting idea

Comment: Watch for the link in the end of my comment, Think of how many cases are there when there are two, three, four and five zeroes attached and apply the principle on the numbers you get. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Answer (score 1):

For this case, and any time there is one less $1$ than $0$'s, there is only one-the one you show.  If you have more $1$'s, the number rises.  Let there be $a\ 1$'s and $b\ 0$'s.  Think of putting all the $0$'s in a line and scattering the $1$'s before, between, and after them.  You require at least one $1$ in each of the between spaces.  If you have a total of $c \  1$'s on the ends, you are looking for a [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of $a-c$ things into $b-1$ pieces, which is ${a-c-1 \choose b-2}$ times the ways of arranging the $c\ 1$'s on the ends, which is $1$ for $c=0$ and $2$ for $c \gt 0$.  The final answer is then $${a-1 \choose b-2}+\sum_{i=1}^{a-b+1}2{a-i-1 \choose b-2}$$